# Different paths Apache

Tags: svn, apache

If apache is installed in different locations of the same server, will the running of one apche have an impact on another apache which is not running?

Answer (score 3):

No there shouldn't be any impact, and I have several apaches running on the same server without issues, but:

- it is best to keep all resources separate (ie not share svn repos by different apaches, otherwise you think an svn repo isn't accessed/used by one apache, while another is still active)
- each apache should have its own set of resources (`svn-auth-file`, `httpd.conf`, ssl certificate), in order to modify those resources without them being blocked/used by another process (another apache running and also using them)
- the port numbers are visible and generally above 1024 (in order to launch an apache without root right). Setting up a reverse proxy is a good practice in order to mask the different full addresses of your different apache services.